# selecting the correct folder in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro that asks you the folder where to save all the graphs of a worksheet using a message box, but at the and the graphs are saved not in the desired folder, but in the parent one.

For example, instead of saving in C:\parent\desiredFolder it saves in C:\parent\

Thank you for your help.

```
Sub EXPORTCHARTS()

MsgBox ("Seleziona la cartella dove vuoi esoportare i grafici")

ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 400

Dim sItem As String
Dim dlgOpenFolder As FileDialog

Set dlgOpenFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
dlgOpenFolder.Filters.Clear

With dlgOpenFolder
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If  .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = dlgOpenFolder

 ' ---------------------------------------------------------
 Dim objCht As ChartObject

 i = 1
 For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    objCht.Chart.Export Filename:=i & ".jpg", FilterName:="JPG"
    i = i + 1
 Next objCht

' ---------------------------------------------------------
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 50

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jbjstam pointed out in their answer that you aren't using the folder name when you are saving the files.

You also had issues with your logic if the user cancelled from the FileDialog as, even if you correctly used `sItem` in your loop, `sItem` would never be set and therefore the files would be being saved to the current directory.

The following should work:

```
Sub EXPORTCHARTS()

    MsgBox ("Seleziona la cartella dove vuoi esoportare i grafici")

    ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 400

    Dim sItem As String
    Dim dlgOpenFolder As FileDialog
    Dim i As Long

    Set dlgOpenFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    dlgOpenFolder.Filters.Clear

    With dlgOpenFolder
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "No path selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

     ' ---------------------------------------------------------
    Dim objCht As ChartObject

    i = 1
    For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        objCht.Chart.Export Filename:=sItem & "\" & i & ".jpg", FilterName:="JPG"
        i = i + 1
    Next objCht

    ' ---------------------------------------------------------
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 50
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the variable fldr in the loop that exports the charts...

Comment: Actually `sItem` or `GetFolder` would be the variables that might contain the path to be used.  `fldr` is just a pointer to a `FileDialog` object.  But the underlying issue is correct - not using the path selected by the user as part of the save.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks for fleshing out a proper answer :-)